# Generic method to insert into hashmap using the Class as key

Tags: java, generics, libgdx

I'm trying to create a method that receives an object that extends Component and insert it into a map that uses the objects class as key to the object itself. For some reason it is complaining about the put call

```
components = new Array<ObjectMap<Class,? extends Component>>();

public <T extends Component> void putComponentOnEntity(Entity e, T component) {
    if (entities.items[e.id] == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Entity does not exist anymore");
    }
    ObjectMap<Class, ? extends Component> entityComponents = components.get(e.id);
    entityComponents.put(component.getClass(), component);
}
```

--

```
The method put(Class, capture#4-of ? extends Component) in the type ObjectMap<Class,capture#4-of ? extends Component> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#5-of ? extends Component>, T)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it then just take `public<Component>`? Can't it then handle the subclasses of Component?

Comment: Why is this method generic in `T`, rather than the whole class? What type is `components`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put anything (except null) inside a `ObjectMap<Class, ? extends Component>`, because `ObjectMap<Class, ? extends Component>` is a map of `Class` and of *some unknown type which extends Component*. So it could be an `ObjectMap<Class, Label>` or an `ObjectMap<Class, Button>`, but we don't know.

Adding any value to such a map would have a big chance of adding something which doesn't have the actual type of the values of the map (for example, a Label, when the map is a map of buttons), so the compiler forbids it.

The compiler must know the actual type hidden behind `?` to check that what you add to the map is compatible with its type. That's what makes the generic types type-safe.

Comment: It's possible if the map is an `ObjectMap<Class, Component>`. Such a map accepts any instance of Component as value.

Comment: It's impossible to make the compiler enforce that the object that you're inserting matches the class that you're inserting.  But you can make this a `HashMap<Class<?>,Object>` and enforce it yourself in code if you need to.